# Remove column after map

Tags: r, purrr

Naive question ahead: I would like to remove a columns after a `map`

Repex:

```
tibble(a = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 5),
       x = runif(10),
       y = runif(10),
       z = runif(10)) %>%
  split(.$a) %>%
  map(`[`, c("x", "y", "z"))
```

selects me the `x`, `y`, and `z` columns of the `tibble`s.

What if I want to **drop** the column `a` instead?
(Same result, but easier for me.)

Comment: `map(~select(.x,-a))`

Comment: If you are allowed to use numeric subsetting, you can just replace `c("x", "y", "z")` by `-1`.

Comment: @GabrielSilva True, although I would prefer to use column name instead.  (Yet, it was not required in the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *base R*

```
map(~.x[grep('a', names(.x), invert = TRUE)])
#OR
map(function(x) x[grep('a', names(x), invert = TRUE)])
```

Using *dplyr*

```
map(~select(.x, -a))
```